# Variable reset to 0 and come with Segementation fault (core dumped) in C

Tags: c

Within a function, I had seven print statements that prints out the value of totalIteration variable. It used to and supposed to remain 77, however, right after my function call to ratio(), the variable turned to 0. I did not modify it anywhere between the two print statements, so I am very confused on why this happened.

Code:

```
float get_running_ratio() {
  int maxCount = 0;
  int maxIteration = 0;
  int totalIteration = 0;
  float avgVal = 0.0;
  totalIteration = get_iteration_no(rand());
  int size = get_arr_size(rand());
  for (int i = 0; i < totalIteration; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", totalIteration); // print statement

    char *arr = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    printf("%d\n", totalIteration); // print statement

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      arr[j] = get_arr_val(rand());
    }
    printf("%d\n", totalIteration); // print statement

    int tem = maxCount;
    printf("%d\n", totalIteration); // print statement

    float temp = ratio(arr, size, &tem);
    printf("%d\n", totalIteration); // print statement

    if (temp > maxCount) {
      maxCount = temp;
      maxIteration = i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", totalIteration); // print statement

    free(arr);
    printf("%d\n", totalIteration); // print statement

    avgVal = avgVal + temp;
  }
  avgVal = avgVal / totalIteration;
  printf("total number of iterations: %d\n", totalIteration);
  printf("the iteration number with the maximum number of vowels: %d",
         maxIteration);
  return avgVal;
}

float ratio(char *arr, int size, int *maxCountPointer) {
  int vowel = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 'A' || arr[i] == 'E' || arr[i] == 'I' || arr[i] == 'O' ||
        arr[i] == 'U') {
      vowel = vowel + 1;
    }
    maxCountPointer[i] = vowel / (size - vowel);
    vowel = 0;
  }
  if (*maxCountPointer < vowel) {
    *maxCountPointer = vowel;
  }
  free(arr);
  return (float)vowel / (size - vowel);
}
```

Output:

```
77
77
77
77
0
0
0
total number of iterations: 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You have `free(arr);` in both the `get_running_ratio` and  the `ratio` function.

Comment: Yeah, I purposefully added that in my ratio function to see if that causes different output, it gives me the same result.

Comment: Use `valgrind` or the address sanitizer to track invalid memory uses.

Answer (score 2):

1. As @Cheatah mentions, you have a double `free()` in `ratio()`.
2. More pressingly, you have `int *maxCountPointer`, which you use

   1. as if it was an array (`maxCountPointer[i] = ...`)
   2. as if it was a regular int pointer (`*maxCountPointer = ...`)

   and since you only pass it a pointer to a single int on stack (`&tem`), that array write ends up overwriting other memory (stack variables in the calling function, for instance).